# Eliminate repetition between Powerpoint slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a powerpoint slideshow with a series of bullet points. I'd like to change it so that each bullet point appears on the next slide. What is the best way to do this?

Instead of copying/pasting, I'd like to have something like where each slide is defined as the one before it, plus something else. That way, if I make a change to one slide, everything downstream is automatically updated.

Or maybe I can do something with transitions where each bullet appears on hitting the arrow key?

I'm using Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [building text on a slide one bullet at a time](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/build-text-on-a-slide-one-bullet-at-a-time-HP001149650.aspx)?

From the article:

> 1. Click the Slides tab and select the slide you want.
> 2. On the Slide Show menu click Animation Schemes.
> 3. In the Slide Design task pane, under Apply to selected slides, click an animation scheme such as Fade in one by one, Wipe, or Dissolve in, in the list.
> 4. Click Play button to review your animation.

I believe that there's a "animate on mouseclick" or something in that pane, I do not have powerpoint presently installed.